# How can a set with one element be equal to a set with two elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm looking into nonstandard analysis, and am in a chapter which introduces the whole load of basic terms they'll use.

One of this is a proof for ordered pairs (Kuratowski definition) by induction. The ordered pairs are defined like this:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(a)_k    :&=\{a\}  \\
(a,b)_{k} :&= \{\{a\},\{a,b\}\} \\
(a_1,\,...\,,a_n)_k :&= ((a_1,\,...\,,a_{n-1}),a_n)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

The theorem to show is :
$(a_1,\,...\,,a_n) = (b_1,\,...\,,b_n) \Rightarrow a_k = b_k \text{  for k = 1, ... , n}$

They do it by induction: Case n = 1 is trivial, and case n = 2 (the part I don't understand) goes like this:

It is $(a_1 , a_2) = (b_1,b_2) $. This is per definition equal to $\{\{a_1\},\{a_1,a_2\}\} = \{\{b_1\},\{b_1,b_2\}\} $.

Now the following cases are possible:
$
\begin{align}
 \{a_1\} &= \{b_1\} &\text{and}&\quad\quad \{a_1,a_2\} &= \{b_1,b_2\}  ,\\
\{a_1\} &= \{b_1,b_2\} &\text{and}& \quad\quad\{b_1\} &= \{a_1,a_2\}
\end{align}
$

First case seems simple enough, but I don't understand how a set with one element can be equal to a set with two elements. Even worse, they say for both cases follows 
$ a_1 = b_1 $ and $ a_2 = b_2$ 
... but why?

Comment: The actual answer is so simple, I think if I didn't ask, I'd never have figured it out ... - Thank you both!

Comment: In the proposition that is to be proven, the thesis has equality between the elements of the tuples. Therefore, the cases should also have equality between elements: $a_1=b_1$ and $\{a_1,a_2\}=\{b_1,b_2\}$ for the first case. $a_1=\{b_1,b_2\}$ and $b_1=\{a_1,a_2\}$ for the second.

Comment: Never mind. It is in the definition where the braces are missing. It should be $(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$.

Comment: It seems a bit odd that a book on nonstandard analysis would spend time building up such set theoretic basics. That would be like having a book on public key cryptography start with a chapter that builds up the natural numbers from the Peano postulates.

Comment: It's a key detail, used to build the super structure. It's a means of creating an order (a first/second), so this super structure can express relations.

Comment: @JohnColeman: I don't agree with your anallogy. Non-standard analysis is (often) proposed as an alternative foundation for analysis, so giving the foundations from the ground up is very appropriate

Comment: @RobArthan Obviously some set theoretic/ logic foundation would be appropriate -- but Kuratowski's construction of ordered pairs? Seems a bit too low-level for the intended application. It is hard to know without seeing the actual book. In any event -- I just said that it struck me as odd, not that I was convinced that it was wrong.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is possible for $\{x\}$ to equal $\{y,z\}$ if and only if $y=z$ -- because then $\{y,z\}$ is actually a set with one element.

Answer (score 47):

Hint: the set $\{1, 1\}$ does not have two elements.